# What should be the correct approach for google login with react-native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, google-signin, expo-auth-session

I am trying to create an expo app that should have google-login with Node.js server. I kind of missing how to handle the project structure / System design for it.

My Current flow is
User press on Google login in the app, and app. And i am using this library for it.

```
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";

const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
androidClientId:
  "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
iosClientId:
  "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
```

});

Using this piece of code i am getting the user's information in the app, but till this moment my Node.js server is not doing anything.

Calling `https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me` i can get the user data, on the mobile app. But i think that is kind of security vulnerability. Am i missing something how to handle this login flow.

[image]

Comment: There are tons of respective tutorials out there on how to do this.

Comment: As of 2021, Google has One Tap Sign-in which is easier to use for end users. Unfortunately I couldn't find a good way to use it with React Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful login in the mobile application:

1. Send the ID token to the server
2. Verify the ID token
3. Create an account or session or whatever the use case requires

See for [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) for details.